# Slide out panel?

Tags: html, css, slide, out, tabslideout

I'm working on a little project and I have this panel down, but I would like to change the "tab" position something like this http://s26.postimg.org/5tr23ln9l/little_text.png
I hope you can help me, loves, I am a bit of a "newbie" here~
http://jsfiddle.net/2YhzT/

```
#purple {
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 11px;
position:fixed;
left:-50px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
x-index:999;
}
```

I think there is something wrong with this part;

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsfiddle.net/2YhzT/6/

Adding this to `#redtab` seems to fix it.

```
position:relative;
top:-19px;
left:100px;
```

[image]

However, using an `display:inline-block` is a better approach. Add this on `#redtab`:

```
display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:100px;
```

Meanwhile, don't forget to add `display:inline-block` on `#red` as well.

**Now, it works on window resize too.**

[image]

**One more**

- http://jsfiddle.net/2YhzT/7/

If you wanted it to show and hide, if I take your image literally, then do this:

1. Add `display:none` to `#redtab` (So by default it is hidden)
2. Once we `hover` over the main navigation element, we can show it by:

   ```
   #purple:hover #redtab {
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

Animation to demonstrate (note the lack of jitter).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2YhzT/4/)**</kbd>

css

```
#purple {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    height:10px;
    left:-50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    x-index:999;
}
#purple:hover {
    left:0px;
}
#purple:hover > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#red {
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border:1px solid;
    border-left:none;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    x-index: 50;
}
#redtab {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-left:none;
    text-align: center;
    height:10px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    width:25px;    
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

---

Or this  <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2YhzT/2/)**</kbd>  according to your image example

css

```
#purple {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    height:10px;
}
#purple:hover > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#red {
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border:1px solid;
    border-left:none;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    x-index: 50;
}
#redtab {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-left:none;
    text-align: center;
    height:10px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    width:25px;    
    font-size: 11px;
}
```